# Access-Control-Allow-Origin header wordpress .htaccess doesn't work

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, cors

I want to allow another site to make a request (get a media file) from my `https://www.domain.de/wp-content/uploads/...`

However when I want to make that request by entering the link to the other website I get the error: `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Then I tried to edit the .htacces file to `Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` but it returns the same error

Any ideas on how to make that work?

EDIT

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Can you try restarting your server with `sudo a2enmod headers`?